# How to use local-link ipv6 for ssh?

Tags: networking, ssh, ipv6

I am able to remotely access my Ubuntu 22.04 PC from my windows' notebook at my local network using ssh

```
ssh <username>@<public ipv6 address> -p <port>
```

Or `ping` it without no problem.

But the public ipv6 are temporary ones, and as local-link ipv6 is permanent (`valid_lft forever`), it would be handy using it.
But it does not work with

```
ssh -6 <username>@<local-link ipv6 address>%<iternfaceLANNumber> -p <port>
```

I just get

> Connection timed out

There are [some questions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1256160/1188532) showing that should work. I tried both with and without brackets, the result is the same.

I am also not able to ping with

```
ping <local-link ipv6 address>%<iternfaceLANNumber>
```

It returns

> unreachable host

From what I have read (like [here](https://www.itdojo.com/ssh-using-link-local-ipv6-addresses/)), we should be able to use the local-link ipv6 when we are in the internal network... How can I enable the `ssh` access using local-link ipv6?

Any help is appreciated.

---

**Some details:**

---

I am accessing (ssh) from anaconda prompt in my Windows PC.

Regarding  <iternfaceLANNumber>,

- With `ip addr` at Ubuntu, I see the network is named `wlp4s`, but that's not what I am using.
- I am using the Windows %14. The % <iternfaceLANNumber> I get using (at windows):

```
    netsh interface ipv6 show address
```

and it says is 14 for wi-fi:

> Interface 1: Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
>
> ...
>
> Interface 14: Wi-Fi

---

I believe I am using the windows default ssh (or maybe some installed with anaconda)... at least I do not remember installing it...

---

That's possible somehow I have messed up, and deactivated the access through local link... I was changing some (privacy) configuration with `nmcli`, `netplan`, etc to see if I can get a permanent public ipv6 address.

So, at Ubuntu, I have:

- edited the `<networkName>.nmconnection` file at `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`.

  - at `[ipv6]`
  - `addr-gen-mode=eui64`
- `nmcli connection edit <network>`

  - `set ipv6.addr-gen-mode 0`
  - `set ipv6.ip6-privacy 1`
- [edited  `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ipv6-privacy.conf`]

  - `net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 0`
  - `net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 0`
  - `net.ipv6.conf.<wlanCode>.accept_ra = 0`
  - `net.ipv6.conf.<wlanCode>.autoconf=1`
  - `net.ipv6.conf.<wlanCode>.use_tempaddr=0`
- Edited the `.yaml` file at `/etc/netplan`

  - `network:`
    *  `version: 2`
    *   `ethernets:`
    *     `<WLancode>:`
    *       `dhcp6: false`
    *       `ipv6-privacy: off`
    *       `ipv6-address-generation: eui64`
    *       `accept-ra: false`
    *   `renderer: NetworkManager`

Comment: I just tried it, and it works on my computers. Note, the `<internalLANNumber>` should be the interface of the local computer, not the remote computer. For example, I was using my laptop WiFi. So, I used `wlo1` of the (local) laptop not the Ethernet interface of the (remote) home server. Yours may be `eno1` or `eth0` or something similar.

Comment: @user68186, thank you for your comment. Yes, I am using %14 (from Windows notebook). Not the wlp4s of my Ubuntu (presented when I look at  `ip addr`). Do you think it is possible that I have messed up, and deactivated the access through local link somehow? I was changing some (privacy) configuration with nmcli, netplan, etc to see if I can get a permanent public ipv6 address...

Comment: Please update your question with more details. Are you using the Windows ssh client, or WSL, If you use Ubuntu directly, you have to use `wlp4s` or whatever `ip addr show` says.

Comment: @user68186, I have updated the question with some details I believe can be pertinent... Thank you again,

Comment: @user68186, I was trying some alternatives here, and I noticed the following: when I deactivate the firewall at the router, I can not just ssh-access using the public ipv6 from outside the local network, as I can access the remote PC (Ubuntu) from my notebook in the local network using the link-local ipv6... I do not feel comfortable in keeping the router firewall deactivated... do you know any way to solve this without deactivating the router firewall? I am sorry if it is a naive question... I am new to this remote access thing...

Comment: If this problem can be solved by deactivating the router firewall, then this is probably not an Ubuntu problem. You may want to configure the firewall tab deactivate it. How to do that is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: Thank you @user68186.